# How to train Tesseract From Scratch?

Tags: lstm, tesseract

I want to train tesseract from scratch, so, I refer to the documentation of tesseract4 and tesseract5.
As follows :
[tesseract5](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/tess5/TrainingTesseract-5.html)
[tesseract4](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/tess4/TrainingTesseract-4.00.html)
I followed the steps and got no errors, but the results were terrible .
After training, the synthesized .traineddata file, I use it to try to test, all errors, almost none of them are correct .

Here are my steps
First, I created a new text named num.txt, this is its content :
`0123456789`

Yes , I just want to train a .traineddata with only numbers from scratch .

Next, I generated a unicharset file from num.txt :
`unicharset_extractor --norm_mode 3 --output_unicharset .\num.lstm-unicharset num.txt`

Generate starter traineddata file (langdata_lstm-main is the unzipped folder of langdata downloaded from github):
`combine_lang_model --input_unicharset num.lstm-unicharset --lang chi_sim --script_dir .\langdata_lstm-main --output_dir .\ --version_str "num:20220908[1,48,0,1Ct3,3,16Mp3,3Lfys64Lfx96Lrx96Lfx512O1c1]" --pass_through_recoder true`

Next, prepare the pictures and box files required for training. The text2image command I used directly here generates .tif and .box files.
[image: View .tif and corresponding .box files through jTessBoxEditorFX]
[image: .box file content]

Generate .lstmf file
`tesseract train.tif train -l chi_sim --psm 7 lstm.train`

Create a new text train_listfile.txt . Write the path where the lstmf file is located

trained
`lstmtraining --traineddata .\chi_sim\chi_sim.traineddata --net_spec "[1,48,0,1 Ct3,3,16 Mp3,3 Lfys64 Lfx96 Lrx96 Lfx512 O1c13]" --model_output .\output\output --train_listfile train_listfile.txt --max_iterations 0 --target_error_rate 0.01 --debug_interval 0`

Wait for a while, and after training, generate a runnable model
`lstmtraining --stop_training --continue_from .\output\output_checkpoint --traineddata .\chi_sim\chi_sim.traineddata --model_output .\output\num.traineddata`

About 5000 pieces of data were trained, and the following are the appalling test results
Test results, the left is the correct answer, the right is the tesseract test result .
[image]

I have checked the tesseract documentation many times, but I still don't know the reason .
Please help me, almighty netizens